# I don't know how to useform action on view razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to save values in salesforce on my form submit button .
I dont know how to use form action method in view razor with validation ....

Here is my code for salesforce which I need to implement on submit button of my form so that it make an entry in salesforce:

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/..." method="POST" >
<input type=hidden name="oid" value="111">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value = "http://test" />
```

here is my view page:

```
@model nd.Models.PopupDemoModel 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>   
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.first_name , new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name )
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email , new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email )
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.phone )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.phone , new {@class="demo-field-longer"})
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.phone )
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="editor-label grid_2">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company )
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company , new { @class = "demo-field-longer" })
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 error long" style="margin-left:250px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company)
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_2 sub-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="editor-field grid_2 submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="demo-submit-button"/><br />
        @ViewData["DemoMessage"]
    </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Any help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "cssClassorId" }))  {

 }
```

Comment: where to pass action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/..." and <input type=hidden name="oid" value="111">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value = "http://test" />

Comment: you can pass action in the beginform method and the other as normal html as a form content.

Comment: @user207888 You can check syntax at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx

Comment: after using in view this @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "cssClassorId" }))  {
can I use in my actionresult in end  return RedirectToAction(salesforce.com/servlet/..",new{oid='111',retURL="test"}; will it work like this?